# retrieve variable from another php file

Tags: php, mysql

i wanted to display the output of the query, but i cant retrieve my variable  $result mainly because it is on a different file but i used the require to get it but i still get the error variable not defined,i wanted to know how can i retrieve the $result that's been on function.php and used it on the search.php to display.

search.php

```
<?php

include "db.php";
include "function.php";

if(isset($_GET['keywords'])){
global $connection;
$keyword = ($_GET['keywords']);
 searchData($keyword);
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="search.php" method="GET">
    <label>
        Search
        <input type="text" name="keywords">
    </label>

    <input type="submit" name="search">

    <div class="form-group">

    <div class="result-count">
        Found <?php echo $query->num_rows; ?>result
    </div>
    <?php
        if($query->num_rows){
            while($r = $query->fetch_rows()){
            }
        }   
    ?>

    </div>

  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

function.php

```
<?php require_once "db.php";?>
<?php
  function searchData($keyword){
global $connection;

$query = ("
          SELECT username
          FROM users
          WHERE username LIKE '%{$keyword}%'
          ");
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

echo "$result->num_rows". "found";
}   
?>
```

db.php

```
<?php

$connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '',
    'loginapp');

    if(!isset($connection)){
        die("Database connection failed!");
    }
```

Comment: You're establishing `$result` in a function `searchData()` so it will be out of scope to use elsewhere. Try having `searchData()` return your result instead then set it like so `$result = searchData();`

Comment: @AaronW. I'm getting error like Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch_rows() in C:\xampp\htdocs\udemy\mysql\search.php:33 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\udemy\mysql\search.php on line 33

Comment: First try to call the function `searchData()` then try to see your query

Comment: already fix thank you guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Arron W.'s comment,  In your function.php file, you will need to return $result, then in search.php you will use load the return into a variable, then use that variable to access the data.

function.php

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

echo "$result->num_rows". "found";
return $result
}   
?>
```

search.php

```
    if(isset($_GET['keywords'])){
    global $connection;
    $keyword = ($_GET['keywords']);
     $result = searchData($keyword);
    }

...

<div class="result-count">
        Found <?php echo $result->num_rows; ?>result
    </div>
    <?php
        if($result->num_rows){
            while($r = $result->fetch_row()){
            }
        }   
    ?>
```

Comment: According to the [comment-formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) page, by surrounding the code in backticks (`)

Comment: You probably have a $query left in your search.php.... replace them all with the $result

Comment: yeah my bad, and now this is the error that i'm getting 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch_rows() in C:\xampp\htdocs\udemy\mysql\search.php:33 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\udemy\mysql\search.php on line 33

Comment: Ahh yes... use fetch_row() instead of fetch_rows()
[FetchRow](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php)